# GoogleWebToolkit, generate JSNI classes from XSD using JAXB or similar tools

Tags: gwt, jaxb, code-generation, jsni

I need to generate JavaScriptObject classes in GWT from XSD such as:

```
class SomeClassFromXSD extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected SomeClassFromXSD() { }

  public static SomeClassFromXSD create() {
     return (SomeClassFromXSD)createObject();
  }

   ............................................    

  public final native void setFiled1(String value) /*-{
    this.Field1 = value;
  }-*/

  public final native String getFiled1() /*-{
    return this.Field1;
  }-*/

   ............................................

}
```

How I can use JAXB to generate such classes? Or maybe another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the inheritance plugin from [**JAXB 2 Basics**](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins) to have your generated classes extend a specific super class:

- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin

Comment: Yes, but main problem that methods body is native Java Script.   /*-{
    return this.Field1;
  }-*/